# Como fazer download de PDF automaticamente no Selenium? Com Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Estou usando Python com o webdriver do Selenium para automatizar o download de vários arquivos PDF. Eu recebo a janela de visualização do PDF. E agora eu gostaria de baixar o arquivo de forma automática sem aparecer a janela (salvar como).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer o download do arquivo com o código abaixo, mas ainda sim continua aparecendo a janela (Salvar como).

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r"C:\downpdf")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")

fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", "true")
btndownpdf = firefox.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="download"]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que depende do site, nem sempre os servidores estão configurados para retornar o *mimetype* `application/pdf` para PDFs.

Basta verificar, através de ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador, qual o exato mimetype que está sendo retornado para esse arquivo, e, então, usá-lo na configuração do `.set_preference()`

Um outro detalhe é que essa configuração precisa ser feita antes da criação do driver:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r"C:\downpdf")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf") # ou outro
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", "true")

firefox = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
# .... codigo para chegar ate o elemento: firefox.get(url) etc
btndownpdf = firefox.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="download"]').click()
```

Comment: Verifiquei o mimetype, e é o application/pdf.

Comment: @Hora editei a resposta, tem a ordem dos elementos também

Answer (score 1):

O selenium é uma ferramenta excelente, mas eu não acho que ele seja "usual" para fazer downloads, nesse caso eu recomento utilizar outra biblioteca, como o urllib (built-in).

Segue um exemplo:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
def download_file(url):
    response = urlopen(url)
    with open("file_down.pdf", "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.read())
        print("Feito!!!")
def main():
    download_file("http://www.secom.ba.gov.br/arquivos/File/MANUALMARCAGOVERNO2015.pdf")
main()
```